# Send email with attachments after a file is generated

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I’m running an approval flow that generates an index.html table file with all items requested.

There is a button to approve all requests and a button to generate a .csv file.

I need to send an email to whoever approves the request (after clicking the “approve all” button) with the .csv file as an attachment. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: node-mailer for example - via defining a tranportagent, mail-header, body, attachments etc.. -> See https://nodemailer.com/about/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer supports different ways of setting [attachments](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/).

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
        

 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'host.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
           user: 'user@gmail.com',
           pass: 'gmailpassword'
      }
});
    
var mailOptions = {
     from: 'sender@gmail.com',
     to: 'receiver@gmail.com',
     subject: 'CSV File',
     text: 'Hello world',
     html: '<b>Hello world</b>',
     attachments: [{
         filename: 'csv-file.csv', // file name
         path: '/path/to/csv-file.csv' // file path
     }]
 };

// send mail
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(info.response);
});
```

you can use convert data into CSV before sending it. Use module like [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse).
NodeMailer -> [Nodemailer Repository GitHub](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer)